# How to generate writable path in FileManager that works in XCTest

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, nsfilemanager, ios-app-group

I am writing an XCTest that involves writing a file to disk. I am using an AppGroup to define the file path. This works fine running on device or simulator.

```
class func filePath()->URL {
    guard let path = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "my.app.group.id") else {
        fatalError("No File Path")
    }
    let filePath = path.appendingPathComponent("filename.json")
    return filePath
}
```

… However the `containerURL` doesn't return something in an XCTest environment. The test crashes.

How can I generate a temporary path that works for Unit Testing?

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but what you can do is to insert TEST_HOST in your test's target under Build Settings.